# SharePoint 2013 workflows are not running at all

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server

I did an upgrade from SP 2010 to SP 2013. I have already installed and configured SharePoint Workflow Manager. I can create and publish workflows of type 2013 but they are not working at all (manually, automatically when a document is created or changed) and I get no error. The workflow status is always blank! However, workflows of type 2010 work fine.

I suspected that the latest SharePoint cumulative update can solve this problem. I downloaded the latest update for “SharePoint Server 2013” from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn789211(v=office.14).aspx but as I want to install it I get the following error and I cannot proceed the installation: “The expected version of the product was not found on the system.”

What is wrong with the SharePoint 2013 workflows? Is it helpful to install the latest SharePoint cumulative update? If yes, why I can’t run it?

Answer (score 0):

I installed SharePoint 2013 that was supposed to have SP1 in it already.
I finally found this article: http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx

The table shows the versions.  In my case 15.0.4569.1506.

The table directs you to download a fixed version of SP1.  I'm installing it now in hopes this will allow me to continue installing the above mentioned patches.

Comment: Thanks for the link. No it is not SharePoint Foundation! it is SharePoint Server. Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (Version: 15.0.4571.1502). Language Pack for SharePoint and Project Server 2013  -German/Deutsch (Version: 15.0.4420.1017).

Answer (score 0):

your SharePoint Foundation 2013, since SP1 has included it per the following faq article.

KB 2880551 - SharePoint Foundation 2013 SP1
KB 2880552 - SharePoint Server 2013 SP1
http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/02/27/sp2013-sp1-faq.aspx

Comment: I just don't get your point! Do you mean that My SharePoint is Foundation edition and not server edition? my SharePoint version is 15.0.4420.1017 which according to your link is a SharePoint Server.